# How to target an attribute of a self defined component in cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm extremely new to cypress and I want to test if I click my a tag, then the video should change but I don't know how to target the video attribute in my `app-video` component:

```
it('button next should show next video', function() {
  cy.visit('/carousel/videos');
  cy.get('[data-cy=videoComponent]') //i want to see the current value
  cy.get('[data-cy=buttonNext]').click();
  // I want to see the next value
});
```

the attribute containing the video object is `@Output() public currentVid: Video;`

Can I target this one and ask it's value to check if it changed?

```html
<div class="body">
  <h3>B-roll & Timelapse</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="videos$ | async as videos; else loadingOrError">
      <div class="vidDiv">
        <app-video [video]="currentVid" data-cy="videoComponent"></app-video>
        <div class="videoControls">
          <a
            mat-raised-button
            (click)="previous()"
            class="controls"
            data-cy="buttonPrevious"
          >
            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
          </a>
          <a
            mat-raised-button
            (click)="next()"
            class="controls"
            data-cy="buttonNext"
          >
            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #loadingOrError>
  <mat-card>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="loadingErrors$ | async as errorMessage; else loading"
      data-cy="appError"
    >
      Error loading the recipe list: {{ errorMessage }}. <br />
      Please try again later.
    </mat-error>
    <ng-template #loading>
      <mat-spinner class="spinner"></mat-spinner>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-card>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML of that section of the page? You need to use that instead of the raw (programmers) javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this syntax:

```js
it('button next should show next video', function() {
  cy.visit('/carousel/videos');
  cy.get('[data-cy=videoComponent]')
    .should('have.attr', '[video]', 'currentVid')
  cy.get('[data-cy=buttonNext]').click();
  cy.get('[data-cy=videoComponent]')
    .should('have.attr', '[video]', 'nextVid')
});
```

This is using the chainer 'attr(name, [value])' of Chai which is explained here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai-jQuery.

Comment: I've been going over your code and it's definitely a step in the right direction but the object doesn't get renamed, the content of the object hower changes (new id and new url) and I'm trying to check that the id of the object in currentVid changes

Comment: Check, I have no experience at all with those kinds of objects in HTML. But I think using ```its()``` would be the last push. How that works is described here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Syntax